# Error 1325.„SharePointData” is not a valid short file name during Sharepoint uninstalling

Tags: sharepoint, uninstallation

Error 1325.„SharePointData” is not a valid short file name

does anyone know why this error is appearing during uninstallation of Windows SharePoint Services 3.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you re-installed SharePoint or moved it about? Something similar happens with Office:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328162/en-us?spid=2533&sid=1339

and is cleaned up by [Windows Installer Cleaner](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301/).